# The Application is in break mode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

somehow I got to make VS2015 show this screen when I pause the application:

[image]

I clicked all of the 3 offered solutions, but none of them would get me back to what I'm used it.

My code is nothing special, I just show a form as .ShowDialog.

The error that occurs right before this is

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

but I'm unable to spot it

Can anybody help?

The first error that is thrown is this:

[image]

Comment: You didn't stop it at a specific point so there's no source code to show. You stopped it during framework and/or system code as your application is probably idle and only in the progress with handling window messages. Place a breakpoint if you want to break at a specific place.

Comment: Oh so there's an error. Is there any other information than the error type?

Comment: I did that. I also made it so that all exception are caught using Debug->Windows->Exception settings. But I still don't get the usual VS breaks.

Comment: Yes, the error that comes up is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll" but I would like to have VS stop at the line where the error occurs. I have desperately tried to find the line question but I wasn't successful, andalso I would like to have VS point me directly who where the error occured.

Comment: @VisualVincent I have added the error to the posting.

Comment: There's no line of source code to show because the error seems to be thrown by the framework itself. I'd say (but I don't know) that it is thrown at a place which you don't control (i.e. you didn't call a method that would throw the error). What happens if you uncheck that exception from the exception settings?

Comment: From your picture it also seems that you cannot view additional info... Strange.

Comment: The IDE just holds forever. I guess I have to take the good old road and remove each component until it works again. :-/ I'm pretty sure it has to do with ActiveX components that I'm using.. I will report back just in case anyone is interested.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you try unchecking it as break always? If you're using ActiveX controls and your IDE freezes without break always, then it is likely an error in those components, yes.

Comment: If I uncheck the exception, the IDE breaks forever. If I don't uncheck it, the application just quits.

Comment: I think my question is legitimate and well-described, so please upvote it so that other people in the same situation can learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: Show the code that displays the dialog. And the code at the Form load event of your dialog?

Comment: Just because someone downvoted it it does not make it _not helpful_. But there has also not been any really helpful responses (apart from you stating that an ActiveX control might be the issue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After activating and de-activating "Enable Just My Code" under Options, the IDE halts on errors again, and I can see where it fails. The strange message is gone.
But now I'm getting a System.Data.Sqlite error in a line where no sqlite is being used.
So I guess something is just majorly messed up and a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Try this in your visual studio, i have faced same error and below option worked for me.

Under Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> CHECK - Use Managed Compatibility Mode

Comment: When I do this I get:  ***The Managed Compatibility mode option is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Visual Studio.  If you have scenarios that still require this option, please file a detailed issue report using Help> Send Feedback > Report a Problem....***

Answer (score -2):

I recently started to use Visual Studio 2017 and ran into this mistake very often. If you are a Visual Studio beginner, it's very likely that you are trying to run a project, but clicked the wrong file. You should either open the .sln solution file or open the whole folder and click the .sln file before running the program. If your project is bug-free and you are following the right procedure, you won't run into the problem shown above. May it helps.